# How special characters must be escaped in openbox config file when assigning shortcut-keys?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, lxde, openbox, xml

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/ five characters need to be escaped in XML documents under some circumstances:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

I tried to use `Winkey-<` as a shortcut-key for some command. I did the following attempts, both failed:

```
<keybind key="W-<">
 <action name="Execute">
<command>lxterminal</command>
</action>
</keybind>


<keybind key="W-&lt;">
 <action name="Execute">
<command>lxterminal</command>
</action>
</keybind>
```

How can I use `Winkey <` as a shortcut-key for some command?

Comment: What other characters are printed on your ***physical key* carrying the `<` character?**

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Just `<` and `>`.

Comment: @Name Are you talking about left or 'left carat' ? On my keyboard, left carat is `shift + , `. If you have a win key, yours should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the "Windows" key is usually referred to as the 'Super' key, or in keymappings as `Super`.

The mapping you are looking for is likely `Super + <`

In open box, however, you need the identifier associated with the key. You can find this by running `xev` command.

This should bring up an interactive window. When you press a key, the identifier for that keystroke should be displayed in this window.

Now it is just a matter of pressing the Windows key and reading the result...

Comment: This does not answser the question. If you try with `W-t` instead of `W-<`, the code works. In openbox config shortcut-keys settings `W` is the `Winkey` or `Super`. The question is not about the Winkey or Super, the question is about `>` character.

Comment: Then sub the word 'windows' in the last line for '<' although that is a shift key, so it is probably `shift + , ` as I said above

Comment: Nate, I have a special AZERTY keybaord and < is directly accessible (without using SHIFT), if I use SHIFT it gives >.

Comment: @Name Did you ever figure out why the mappings weren't working as expected? If no, that is it, The config cannot tell that you have a special keyboard. All it sees is a utf-8 (or ascii etc.) code. Normally, config keymappings will be subdivided into "windows" layout and "mac" layout. When you push `[<]` on your keyboard, it sees the same code as when it parses `[shift] + [ , ] ` on the Win section of the config. If you don't mind, try to map the > key using the ` [shift] + [ , ] ` to see if it works.